# How do I format curly braces with pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, braces

I would like to illustrate the set $A = (-\infty,1] \cup [2,+\infty) $ using curly braces as in the figure below.

However, to express the left-hand side and right-rand side infinity, I would like to make the curly braces ending as straight lines. How can I do this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Axis
\draw (0,0) -- (6,0) node[below]{$ x $};

% A
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2,aspect=0.5}]
(2,-1)--(0,-1) node[pos=0.5, below, font=\normalsize] (b1) {} node[left] at (0,-1) {straigt ending here ...};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2,aspect=0.5}]
(6,-1)--(4,-1) node[pos=0.5, below, font=\normalsize] (b2) {} node[right] at (6,-1) {... straigt ending here};

\draw[very thin] (b1)--(1,-1.5) node[below] {$A$} node[below right=3pt] (c1) {};

\draw[very thin] (b2)--(c1) {};

% x-axis labels
\draw[very thin] (2,-0.1) -- (2,0.1) node[below] at (2,-0.1) {$ 1 $};
\draw[very thin] (4,-0.1) -- (4,0.1) node[below] at (4,-0.1) {$ 2 $};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: figure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply draw a white (paper-color) rectangle over the end of the brace.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Axis
\draw (0,0) -- (6,0) node[below]{$ x $};

% A
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2,aspect=0.5}]
(2,-1)--(0,-1) node[pos=0.5, below, font=\normalsize] (b1) {};
\filldraw[white] (0,-1) rectangle ++(.07,-.1);

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2,aspect=0.5}]
(6,-1)--(4,-1) node[pos=0.5, below, font=\normalsize] (b2) {};
\filldraw[white] (6,-1) rectangle ++(-.07,-.1);

\draw[very thin] (b1)--(1,-1.5) node[below] {$A$} node[below right=3pt] (c1) {};

\draw[very thin] (b2)--(c1) {};

% x-axis labels
\draw[very thin] (2,-0.1) -- (2,0.1) node[below] at (2,-0.1) {$ 1 $};
\draw[very thin] (4,-0.1) -- (4,0.1) node[below] at (4,-0.1) {$ 2 $};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can `clip` a rectangle inside a `scope`. In this case, you can place a node inside the `scope` and after the scope use the node to position the ellipsis.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Axis
\draw (0,0) -- (6,0) node[below]{$ x $};

% A
\begin{scope}
\clip (.08,-1)node(A){} rectangle ++(2,-.5);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2,aspect=0.5}]
(2,-1)--(0,-1) node[pos=0.5, below, font=\normalsize] (b1) {};
\end{scope}
\node[left] at (A){$\cdots$};

\begin{scope}
\clip (5.92,-1)node(B){} rectangle ++(-2,-.5);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2,aspect=0.5}]
(6,-1)--(4,-1) node[pos=0.5, below, font=\normalsize] (b2) {};
\end{scope}
\node[right] at (B){$\cdots$};

\draw[very thin] (b1)--(1,-1.5) node[below] {$A$} node[below right=3pt] (c1) {};

\draw[very thin] (b2)--(c1) {};

% x-axis labels
\draw[very thin] (2,-0.1) -- (2,0.1) node[below] at (2,-0.1) {$ 1 $};
\draw[very thin] (4,-0.1) -- (4,0.1) node[below] at (4,-0.1) {$ 2 $};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks good, thank you. I was looking for a way to change the format of the braces, maybe with `pic`, but this solution might be simpler and the way to go.

Comment: I tried to implement the solution, but I found a problem. I need to include the figure over a colored background. The white rectangle shows up. With the clip, I cannot include the "...", which indicates that the braces continue toward the left or right. Is there a way to clip and then include the "..." above the clipped figure?

Comment: @Andre: I edited my solution.

Comment: That is fine. Thank you!